# Select an Image to appear in a div as a bg-img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm build a digital poster editor and so i need help setting an image as a background look of a div. I have no clue where to start

I created a div with a couple of images to select from and a empty div with just a div id.

Here is my images div:

```
<div id="imgopt">
    <ol>
        <li>
            <img src="asset/img/template1.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="asset/img/template2.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="asset/img/template3.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="asset/img/template4.jpg">
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

here is my Empty Div:

```
<div id="designPoster">

</div>
```

Basic i need help writing the js code or a bit of direction on how to implement this functionality of setting a background image of the empty `div[id="designPoster"]` by just selecting the an image from `div[id="imgopt"]`.

Comment: Pure Javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/5rLs3meo/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that with Javascript without jQuery, here is how you could achieve it.
Note that I changed the image to have a working example.

```js
var imageElts = document.querySelectorAll("#imgopt img");
var posterElt = document.querySelector("#designPoster");

for (var i = 0; i < imageElts.length; i++) {
  imageElts[i].addEventListener("click", changeBgImage);
}

function changeBgImage(e) {
  posterElt.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + e.target.src + ")";
  posterElt.style.backgroundSize = "contain";
  posterElt.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
}
```

```css
#imgopt img {
cursor: pointer;
width: 100px;
height: auto;
}

#designPoster {
width: 400px;
height: 157px;
background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgopt">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <img  src="https://i0.wp.com/wptavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/stack-overflow.png?ssl=1">
    </li> 
    <li>
      <img  src="https://i0.wp.com/wptavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/stack-overflow.png?ssl=1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img  src="https://i0.wp.com/wptavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/stack-overflow.png?ssl=1">
    </li>
    <li>
     <img  src="https://i0.wp.com/wptavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/stack-overflow.png?ssl=1">
   </li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div id="designPoster"></div>
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `img src` is the background you would like to set:

```
$('#imgpot img').onClick(function(){
    $('#designPoster').css('background-image', `url(${this.attr('src')})`);
});
```

What this will do is add an event handler to each image tag within `#imgpot`, when clicked, it will assign the `background-image` property of `#designPoster` to the clicked images `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you are asking...

```js
$(function() {

   $('#imgopt img').on('click', function() {
     var imageSource = $(this).prop('src');
     $('#designPoster').css('background-image', 'url('+imageSource+')');  
     
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgopt">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <img  src="asset/img/template1.jpg">
    </li> 
    <li>
      <img  src="asset/img/template2.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img  src="asset/img/template3.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
     <img  src="asset/img/template4.jpg">
   </li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div id="designPoster">

</div>
```